# Difficulties in deploying my own workflow in alfresco workflow console

Tags: workflow, alfresco

I'm following the "Alfresco Developer Series Advanced Workflows" guide of Jeff Potts but I have some difficulties in deploying the simple helloworld workflow.

I'm using alfresco workflow console and i read that if i need to deploy the HelloWorld.bpmn.xml file i can use deploy command followed by the path in which my workflow lives.

But alfresco return always the same error

```
Ultimo comando: deploy /alfresco/workflow/HelloWorld.bpmn.xml Durata: 1ms
----- Syntax Error.
```

What's wrong with that?

Comment: Is there any more of a stacktrace / message to go with the error, which explains where the syntax error comes from? And if not, have you tried running an XML validator against the file to check it's at least valid XML?

Comment: Is this the correct path relative to the classpath?

Comment: thank you all guys for your time. I've solved it using a spring context file.

Answer (score 1):

Read 'help' once again :o)

try to specify engine of WF

```
deploy activiti /alfresco/workflow/HelloWorld.bpmn.xml 
deploy jbpm /alfresco/workflow/HelloWorld.bpmn.xml
```